# Convert a 2d character list into a list of strings using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I aim to convert a 2d character list into an list of strings, whose characters were the individual values of the former lists using Python.

Example:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

Should be returned as

```
['abcd', 'efgh']
```

This should be by joining the values of the former lists inside the original list together into one string.

Comment: Use `join` & try ..

Comment: First post a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, cause the "example" you post is not valid code... And the solution is a simple join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the 2D list (list is the term for an array used in Python):

```
data = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"]]
```

Next you can loop through each list inside the `data` list and assign the new value to the original value in the list:

```
idx = 0
for x in data:
    data[idx] = "".join(x)
    idx += 1
```

This will return the required output.

Full Code:

```
data = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"]]
idx = 0
for x in data:
    data[idx] = "".join(x)
    idx += 1
```

Test your code by adding the following two lines:

```
print(f'First value in list: {data[0]} and second value in list: {data[1]}')
```

**Explanation:**

```
data = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"]]
```

The line of code above assigns the 2D list to a variable to be used on later.

```
idx = 0
```

The variable `idx` is used to assign the required value to each of the former values of the 2D list `data`. You can also assign each value to a separate list by using the `.append` method.

```
for x in data:
```

This loops through each value (or list) inside of the list `data`, using the variable `x` to be referenced as in the code. This can also be done using a `while` loop.

```
data[idx] = "".join(x)
```

This assigns the former value with the index of `idx` in the list with the new value. This uses the python `.join` method to connect the values in the list by a "".

To read more about the Python `.join` method visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp

```
idx += 1
```

This is used to add `1` to the former value of `idx` so that it outputs the new index of the next value in the list used in the `for` loop.

**Testing Your Code**

```
print(f'First value in list: {data[0]} and second value in list: {data[1]}')
```

the above line of code is a simple formatted string that outputs the first `data[0]` and second `data[1]` values of the variable `data`.

I hope this helps you with your coding and understanding your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> data = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g", "h"]]
>>> ["".join(d) for d in data]
['abcd', 'efgh']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[""join(d) for d in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
>>> data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
>>> list(map(''.join, data))
['abcd', 'efgh']
```